# Bamboo wallboard

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I am looking for a better bamboo wallboard.
The wallboard provided by bamboo itself is not sufficient as it does only permit four colums and we have a ton of builds to monitor. The font is also too small to read from a distance.

Are there any good tools to create a nice wallboard for CI/Bamboo that work?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Greasmonkey and tinkering with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Atlasboard project we use for our dashboards. It has tons of customizable components to present info from Atlassian products: https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/guest-blog-using-atlasboard-create-testing-boards